# LibGDX: boundsInFrustrum and BoundingBox not working as expected

Tags: java, math, libgdx, collision-detection

I am loading a box2d scene from a json file. This scene contains a fixture marking the bounding box that the camera is allowed to travel in. Using this mechanism works fine for the lower and left bounds, yet fails completely for the upper and right bounds, which is rather odd.

Here is the part that loads the bounding box from the file:

```
PolygonShape shape = ((PolygonShape) fixture.getShape());
Vector2 vertex = new Vector2();
float boundLeft = world.startX, boundRight = world.startX, boundUp = world.startY, boundLow = world.startY; // The location of the camera as initial value

for (int i = 0; i < shape.getVertexCount(); i++) { // Itarate over each vertex in the fixture and set the boundary values
    shape.getVertex(i, vertex);
    vertex.add(body.getPosition());
    boundLeft = Math.min(vertex.x, boundLeft);
    boundLow = Math.min(vertex.y, boundLow);
    boundRight = Math.max(vertex.x, boundRight);
    boundUp = Math.max(vertex.y, boundUp);
}

// Build the bounding boxes with enough thickness to prevent tunneling on fast pans
world.boundLeft = new BoundingBox(new Vector3(boundLeft - 5, boundLow - 5, 0).scl(RenderingSystem.PPM), new Vector3(boundLeft, boundUp + 5, 0).scl(RenderingSystem.PPM));
world.boundRight = new BoundingBox(new Vector3(boundRight, boundLow - 5, 0).scl(RenderingSystem.PPM), new Vector3(boundRight + 5, boundUp + 5, 0).scl(RenderingSystem.PPM));
world.boundUp = new BoundingBox(new Vector3(boundLeft - 5, boundUp, 0).scl(RenderingSystem.PPM), new Vector3(boundRight + 5, boundUp + 5, 0).scl(RenderingSystem.PPM));
world.boundLow = new BoundingBox(new Vector3(boundLeft - 5, boundLow - 5, 0).scl(RenderingSystem.PPM), new Vector3(boundRight + 5, boundLow, 0).scl(RenderingSystem.PPM));
// world is a class containing some properties, including these BoundingBoxes
// RenderingSystem.PPM is the amount of pixels per metre, in this case 64
```

And the following part is called when the camera is panned around:

```
public void pan(float x, float y) {
    Vector3 current = new Vector3(camera.position);
    camera.translate(-x, y);
    camera.update(true);
    if (camera.frustum.boundsInFrustum(world.boundLeft) || camera.frustum.boundsInFrustum(world.boundRight)) {
        camera.position.x = current.x; // Broke bounds on x axis, set camera back to old x
        camera.update();
    }
    if (camera.frustum.boundsInFrustum(world.boundLow) || camera.frustum.boundsInFrustum(world.boundUp)) {
        camera.position.y = current.y; // Broke bounds on y axis, set camera back to old y
        camera.update();
    }
    game.batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
}
```

Comment: why dont you talk to the libdx guys theres alot of people complaining about ths library!

Comment: Oh, I'm not complaining. LibGDX is the love of my life and I'd marry it any second, it's just that often I'm not as smart as the LibGDX guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I figured it out. Guess what my world.startx and world.startY were defined as? That's right, they were in screen coordinates:

```
world.startX = start.getPosition().x * RenderingSystem.PPM;
world.startY = start.getPosition().y * RenderingSystem.PPM;
```

This was causing the Math.max to always pick the world.startX and world.startY as these values were absolutely massive in comparison.